# What is name of this card game?

Tags: identify-this-game

I played this card game with my mom back in the 70's. Sometimes we played with more than 2 players.  Each player had their own deck of cards.  I can't remember exactly how we played, but I think we each had a pile of cards to play from in front of us face down (maybe 21 cards in stack/pile but not sure).  There were 4 slots/piles to play from/on on. 4 piles were either beside our playing stack or in front of each of us.  I also think there was a pile/base/stack of cards in the middle face down. I don't remember if we had cards in our hands or not.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for your question! Are there *any* additional details you can give us? For example, do players take turns or is this a game of speed? is the game associated with any particular culture? etc, anything might help.

Answer (score 3):

The descriptions sound a little like a game I played at school and was know by us (possible as local dialect) as Slam.

Doing a google search I've found [double patience] which matched your description.[1](https://www.pagat.com/patience/double.html)

28 cards are played out in 7 piles with 1-7 in each (if you recalled 21 then then would work as 6 piles 1-6 in each)

The object is to get rid of your cards onto central piles.

It's possible to play with multiple players if each player has their own deck.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the game Speed to me. Here is a link to a website about [Speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_(card_game)).
Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jk1SYPCCFn4) as well.
Hope this helps.